# php + mysql + queries errors

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a database that contains 2 tables

user

- user_name,
- first_name,
- last_name,
- address,
- district_name,
- village_name,
- birth_date,
- email_address,
- specialization_id,
- password,
- registered_date

specialization

- specialization id
- specialization_name

i wrote these 2 queries  to make first  select the specialization_id from the specialization table that is the same in the user table

in the second query
i need to insert the specialization_id in the user table as a foreign key for the specialization table but i got an error **Resource id #7**

## query 1

```
 $query_select_spec = mysql_query("SELECT specialization_name FROM specialization, user WHERE user.specialization_id = specialization.specialization_id")or die(mysql_error());
    echo $query_select_spec;
```

## query 2

```
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, address, district_name, village_name, birth_date, email_address, specialization_name, password, registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$country', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$pass1',  now())")or die("could not insert data");
```

## this is the code of the register .php

```
<?php require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); ?>


<?php
ob_start();
 function countryQuery(){

  $countryData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country") or die("could select database");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($countryData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['country_name'] .  '">' . $record['country_name'] . '</option>';

  }

}


function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

function districtQuery(){

$distData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM districts");

  while($recorddist = mysql_fetch_array($distData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recorddist['district_name'] .  '">' . $recorddist['district_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}

function villageQuery(){

$villageData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM village");

  while($recordvillage = mysql_fetch_array($villageData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordvillage['village_name'] .  '">' . $recordvillage['village_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}



 //default value
$message = "Fields Marcked with an [*] are Required";
  $username = "";
  $fname = "";
  $lname = "";
  $specialization = "";
  $email = "";
  $pass1 = "";
  $pass2 = "";
  $district = "";
  $village = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
  $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
  $bdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  //$local_adress = $_POST['adress'];
  $specialization = $_POST['specialization'];
  $district = $_POST['district'];
  $village = $_POST['village'];

  //error handeling
  if((!$username)||(!$fname)||(!$lname)||(!$email)||(!$pass1)||(!$pass2)||(!$specialization)||(!$district)||(!$village)){
  $message = "**** Please insert the Required Fields below ****<br />";

  if($fname == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter First name<br/>";
 }
  if($lname == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter Last name<br/>";
 }

 if($specialization == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your Job<br />";
 }
 if($district == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your District<br />";
 }
 if($village == 0)
 {
     $message = $message . "Select Your Village<br />";
 }
 if($email == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter Email Adress<br/>";
 }
  if ($username == "") {
    $message = $message . "Enter User Name<br/>";
  }

  if($pass1 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "Enter password<br/>";
 }

  if($pass2 == "")
 {
     $message = $message . "rechek the password <br/>";
 }

 } 

     elseif(strlen($pass1) <= 8)
    {
     $message = $message . "Your Password must be at least 8 charachters<br />";
}
   else if($pass1!=$pass2){
   $message = "your password do not match!";
   }else{
   //securing the data
   $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
   $fname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$fname);
   $lname = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$lname);
   //$pass1 = sha1($pass1);

   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   // checking for duplicate
   $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '$username'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the username");
   $count_username = mysql_num_rows($user_query);

    $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT email_address FROM user WHERE email_address = '$email'LIMIT 1") or die("could not check the email");
   $count_email = mysql_num_rows($email_query);

    if($count_username > 0){
     $message = " your username is alredy in use";
    }elseif($count_email > 0){
      $message = "your email is alredy in use";
    }
   else{
    $query_select_spec = mysql_query("SELECT specialization_name FROM specialization, user WHERE user.specialization_id = specialization.specialization_id")or die(mysql_error());

    echo $query_select_spec;
    exit();
      $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, address, district_name, village_name, birth_date, email_address, specialization_id, password, registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$country', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$pass1',  now())")or die("could not insert data");    

    $message = "you have  now been registered";
    //from the social website

    $getid = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $getid['user_rid'];
            $_SESSION['login'] = 'true';
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $getid['username'];
    //header("Location: home.php");
    }
   }
 }




?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register Page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/imagesGallery.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>


<table width="200" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="web_header copy.jpg" alt="visitor header" width="1080" height="128" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>




     <td>
       <marquee direction="left" width="99%" behavior="alternate">
        <img src="imggallery/images/akoura/akoura_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/ballaa2/ballaa2_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/baalbeck/baalbek_small.jpg" height="92">
        <img src="imggallery/images/barouk/cedre_barouk_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/batroun/batroun_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/bchareh/bchareh_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/beiteldin/beiteldine_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/beyrouth/beyrouth_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/beyrouth/beyroyj frm sky/beyrouthfromSky_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        <img src="imggallery/images/deir el mara/deirelamar_small.jpg" width="119" height="91">
        </marquee>
        <hr />
       <h2 class="registerTitle">Registration Fields</h2>
       <h4 class="registerTitle">Sign Up Today....</h4>
 <!-- <div class="container center"> -->
       <p style="color:#FF0000" align="center"><?php print("$message")?></p>
    </td>

    <tr>
        <table width="680" border="0" align="center">
        <form action="register.php" method="post">



         <td> 
        </span><label for="firstname"><span class="Fields">First Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" /></td>

      <td><span class="Fields">Last Name</span><span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>

      <td><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" /></td>



    <tr>
      <td><label for="birthdate" class="Fields">Birth Date                     </label></td>
      <td><input type="date" name="birthdate" value= "YYYY_MM_DD"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'YYYY_MM_DD') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YYYY_MM_DD';}" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
      <td><select name="country"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Country --</option>
        <?php countryQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="specialisation">Specialisation <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="specialization"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Specialization --</option>

        <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="district">District<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="district"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your District --</option>

        <?php districtQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

      <td class="Fields"><label for="village">Village<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><select name="village"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Village --</option>

        <?php villageQuery(); ?>
      </select></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="email">Email Adress<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" />
        <br /></td>
      <td><label for="username"><span class="Fields">User Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="password">Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" />
        <br /></td>
      <td class="Fields"><label for="password2">Re_Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Validate Password" />
        <br /></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Register"/></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

  </form>
</table>
<!--</div>-->
  </tr>



  <tr>
    <td><?php require_once('footer.php'); ?></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

anyone can help me ??

Comment: the `user` table does not contain `specialization_id`

Comment: try executing directly on the database server, if you have any error messages, post it here.

Answer (score 4):

it's not an error, it is what mysql_query returns.
to get values, you should loop through mysql result

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

query1= You do not have specilization_id in user field. and you are using it-user.specialization_id
try `user` in 2nd query instead of user as it may be a keyword.

Comment: my bad i meant specialization_id not specialization_name   edit my question  sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_select_spec = mysql_query("SELECT specialization_name FROM specialization, user WHERE user.specialization_id = specialization.specialization_id")or die(mysql_error());
$row_select_spec = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_select_spec);

$specialization = $row_select_spec['specialization_name'];

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(user_name, first_name, last_name, address, district_name, village_name, birth_date, email_address, specialization_name, password, registered_date)VALUES('$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$country', '$district', '$village', '$bdate', '$email', '$specialization', '$pass1',  now())") or die("could not insert data");
```

Comment: i tried these query but i get a 0  as value

Comment: none of these solution work  i need help to fix i will edit my question and display the code maybe anyone would help me

Comment: You need to check your joins

Comment: i edit the question and add the code of the register page can you help me  with the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

First, i would advise you to refrain from using the old and obsolete mysql extension and rather upgrade to either the mysqli or the PDO extensions. What you ahve there is no error and you just need to loop through the result.

I would do that like this using the mysqli extension.

```
//Connect to the db using the mysql improved extension
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

//Select spec
$query = "SELECT specialization_name FROM specialization, user WHERE user.specialization_id = specialization.specialization_id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//Print results
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo'<pre>'; // Format your dump as code
var_dump($data);
}
```